# Cassandra tablestats showing 0.0 percent repaired after full repair

Tags: cassandra

I have a C* 3.11 cluster of 4 nodes and RF is 3. After I ran a `nodetool repair -full ks1 tb1`, and the command windows shows

`Starting repair command #18 (xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx), repairing ks1 with repair options (parallelism: parallel, primary range: false, incremental: false, job threads: 1, ColumnFami
lies: [device], dataCenters: [], hosts: [], # of ranges: 404, pull repair: false)`

And

`[2018-01-01 01:25:57,730] Repair completed successfully
[2018-01-01 01:25:57,734] Repair command #18 finished in 29 seconds`

So I presume the repair ran successfully. Nonetheless, when I check `nodetool tablestats ks1.tb1`, the command window shows

`Percent repaired: 0.0`

Depending on the tables, the result could be `Percent repaired: 100.0` or `Percent repaired: 70.0` and many still shows `Percent repaired: 0.0`, even though the repair command shows repaired successfully.

What did I miss here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The percent repaired metric is for incremental repair. With incremental repair theres 2 sets of sstables. Repaired and Unrepaired. Once an sstable has been repaired it will be moved to the repaired set and no longer be involved in future repairs. When you put --full your specifying to not use incremental but a subrange repair which is still necessary in some situations to repair the entire data set within a some range regardless of if its been repaired previously or not. Example scenario is a disk failure on 1 host in non-local DC so repair to bring replacement up to date from backup, or a single node past hinted handoff window etc.

To have the 2 sets of sstables has a lot of overhead (locking sstables during repairs from compactions, and anticompaction when ranges split an sstable). So when non-incremental repairs run the sstables are not marked since they avoid those steps.